# Refresh ChildItems in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented the expandable Recycler view & its working fine. I need to refresh the child items with respect to parent item click. How to achieve it?

Comment: what parent? pls draw a sketch a show some code!

Answer (score 0):

Try searching about notifydatasetchanged() for recyclerview adapters.
[Try reading this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.. When I was click the header Item I set background to that selected item,after I call the notifydatasetChanged method , the background is removed....